# How to get the least number after deleting k digits from the input number

Tags: c, algorithm, data-structures

For example, if the input number is `24635`, the least number is `23` after deleting any 3 digits.

It's not the same as taking the two smallest digits, because the order of the digits must be maintained.

Comment: 23 is a nice number but I'm totally not getting it. I'd expect 24 or 35, depending on whether you eliminate digits from the front or the back.

Comment: @AdityaGoel Are you suggesting deleting 3 *`char`s*? (24) Right sifting 3 times? (3079) Deleting 3 hex digits? (6)

Comment: Do you mean you want to keep the two *lowest* digits? Or rather, remove the X *highest* digits. If you do then here's a hint: It will be much simpler if you *sort* the collection of digits.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg, it's not the same as keeping the two lowest digits. The final number, in decimal form, must be in the same order as in the original. e.g. In `43331`, we can have `41` but  not `14`. Therefore `31` is the smallest possible - `14` is not attainable

Comment: I have just edited the example in the question, but I kind of regret it as it will be confusing to read discussion based on the old numbers? Can I just 'undo' my edit?

Comment: You could build a graph and do a search with backtracking on it. Doing some pruning you could even make it reasonably fast. However, as with any such homework question, what have you tried so far?

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt - we've already had logarithms and qsort, there is **really** no need for graphs and backtracking!

Answer (score 28):

Deleting `k` digits means keeping `n - k` digits, where `n` is the total number of digits.

Use a stack that you keep sorted ascendingly. You remove elements from it as long as you can still make it to `n - k` digits and your current element is smaller than the top of the stack:

```
push(2) => 2
push(4) because 2 < 4 => 24
push(6) because 4 < 6 => 246
pop() because 3 < 6 and we can still end up with 2 digits => 24
pop() for the same reason => 2
push(3) => 23
push(5) => 235
```

Then just take the first `k` digits => `23`. Or you can make sure never to push more than `k` digits, and then the final stack is your solution.

Note that you cannot pop elements if that means you will not be able to build a solution of `k` digits. For this, you need to check the current number of elements in the stack and the number of digits to the right of your current position on the input number.

Pseudocode:

```
stack = []
for each d in digits:
  while !stack.empty() and d < stack.top() and (*):
    stack.pop()

  if stack.size() < n - k:
    stack.push(d)

 (*) - exercise, fill in the condition that prevents you 
       from popping elements if you still want to be able to get to a solution.
 Hint: count how many elements the for loop went over already
       and see how many are left. Also consider how many you have left in the stack.
```

Since each element enters and leaves the stack at most once, the complexity is `O(n)`.

Comment: Your complexity analysis is wrong. O(n) means each element is considered only once. For any number in the input it may have to be compared against *all* previous numbers (which have already been compared upon insertion.)

Comment: @JonathanMee - no, it's correct actually. First of all, `O(n)` does not mean each element is considered only **once**, it means each element is considered only a **constant number of times**. That constant, in my case, is around `2`. For any digit in the input, it will only be compared with the elements in the stack. Indeed, we might have a case where we compare with all the elements in the stack, but then we will also have emptied the stack after this, so it reduces future work. Look at it as how many times each element in the stack is accessed (inserted/removed) and you will see it's `O(n)`.

Comment: The dead give away that you're wrong is this algorithm will require a nested `for` loop. Looks O(NlogN) to me.

Comment: @JonathanMee - yes it will, or a `while` nested in a `for`. That doesn't say anything about the complexity and it's not a dead give away for anything. More nested loops does not always equal higher complexity. If you don't believe me, you can implement it and see how long it takes for a million digits or you can open a new question about it. It's definitely `O(n)`, for the arguments I have outlined in the previous comment.

Comment: I don't really have the patience to implement something that is so much more complex than what I've already done. But I will leave you with a quote to help you understand what O(n) is: "it means each element is considered only a **constant number of times**." Your solution does not consider each element a constant number of times. For example the number: 122212221, Will cause the second 1 to make four compares against other numbers in the stack. what 4 compares? Add another 2 before it. The complexity is **not** constant.

Comment: @JonathanMee - yes, it will cause the second `1` to pop all the twos. Each two was pushed once, and now it will be popped, so we've done a constant number of operations for each `2`. Then you push the other twos, and you pop them when you insert the final `1`. If you do the math, you will see that the total number of comparisons, pushes and pops is around `2 * number of digits`.

Comment: It's Ugh... It's like I can't stop myself from trying to explain, `n = number_of_digits` if for each element of `n` if you had to (worst case) every other element that's O(n*n). Since the number of times you have to compare an element of `n` is based on `n` (the `number_of_digits`) this cannot be an O(n) solution, because `n` is not constant.

Comment: @JonathanMee - That's what I'm trying to tell you, you don't compare each element of `n` with every other element! That cannot happen. If you compare one element with a lot of other elements of `n`, then those "a lot of other elements" will be removed from the stack and nothing will be compared with them ever again. The number of times you have to compare a **fixed** element of `n` with other elements of `n` depends on the actual input, but the number of times you have to compare **all** elements of `n` with other elements of `n` is **linear in `n`**, so the whole thing is also linear.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69903/discussion-between-jonathan-mee-and-ivlad).

Comment: Just as a general public notice, [IVlad](http://stackoverflow.com/users/270287/ivlad) is right on the big-O notation. In the worst case this algorithm performs 2n-1 compares so that is *O(n)* time.

Comment: @IVlad

Will this algorithm work for numbers in descending order? Eg - 6 5 4 3 2 1?
If we sort the elements, won't it affect the order of numbers. Or I guess, we are having a separate stack just to know the numbers we are going to keep in the answer, and the order will be decided from the main array.??

Comment: @BhavukMathur we don't actually sort the digits, we just keep the stack in which we insert them sorted. The order will still be maintained. For your example and let's say `k = 2`, we'd do (`|` separates a step, stack contents are listed): `-6 | 5 | 4 | 3 | 2 | 21`, which is the correct answer.

Answer (score 3):

Offer a recursive approach.

On each iteration test for success `k == 0` ...
or failure `num == 0` as there are no digits left to remove.
(returning 10 is worse than some other path that would return `num`.)

Otherwise recurse in 2 ways:
1) Keep the least-significant-digit and try with upper digits.
2) Drop the least-significant-digit and try with upper digits, `k--`
Return the better one.

```
unsigned reduce(unsigned num, unsigned k) {
  if (k <= 0) {
    return num;  // Success
  }
  if (num == 0) {
    return 10;  // Fail
  }
  unsigned path1 = reduce(num/10, k)*10 + num%10;
  unsigned path2 = reduce(num/10, k-1);
  return path1 < path2 ? path1 : path2;
}

int main(void) {
  printf("%u\n", reduce(246, 2));
  printf("%u\n", reduce(24635, 3));
  printf("%u\n", reduce(53642, 3));
  printf("%u\n", reduce(21, 1));
}

2
23
32
1
```

This solution does not depend on knowing the number of digits, just the number needed to remove.

Comment: The complexity of this is probably the worst here, but I couldn't believe that something this simple would solve the problem +1.

Answer (score 2):

Very simple solution.

We have `n` digits, and we must remove `k` of them to leave `n-k`. We can easily identify what the first digit  will be.

The final `n-k-1` digits clearly cannot be the first digit of the answer, there simply aren't enough digits after to make a sufficiently long enough number.

We therefore simply ignore the final `n-k` digits, and focus on the first `k` digits and find the smallest digit in that collection of `k` digits. That will be the first digit of our answer. e.g. all three-digit numbers 5XX are smaller than all number of the form 6XX, regardless of what the Xs are.  (If there is a tie, where two digits share the honour of being smallest, then choose the number on the left as it gives you more flexibility later.)

Now you know what the first digit is, you can ignore it and everything to the left and repeat the whole thing recursively with the remaining digits - what is the smallest number I can make out of the remaining digits?

Answer (score 2):

To solve this, you can follow these steps −

- Define a stack st, create an empty string ret
- n := size of num
- for i in range 0 to n – 1
- while k is non zero and stack is not empty and top of stack > num[i]
- delete from the stack and decrease k by 1
- insert num[i] into st
- while k is not 0, delete element from the stack
- while the stack is not empty
- ret := ret + top of stack, delete element from stack
- now reverse the ret string
- ans := an empty string, and i := 0
- while i < size of ret and ret[i] is not ‘0’
- increase i by 1
- for i < size of ret
- ans := ans + ret[i]
- ret := ans
- return “0” if size of ret is 0, otherwise, ret

C++ solution:

```
class Solution {
public:
   string removeKdigits(string num, int k) {
      stack st;
      string ret = "";
      int n = num.size();
      for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
         while(k && !st.empty() && st.top() > num[i]){
            st.pop();
            k--;
         }
         st.push(num[i]);
      }
      while(k--)st.pop();
      while(!st.empty()){
         ret += st.top();
         st.pop();
      }
      reverse(ret.begin(), ret.end());
      string ans = "";
      int i = 0;
      while(i <ret.size() && ret[i] == '0')i++;
      for(; i < ret.size(); i++)ans += ret[i];
      ret = ans;
      return ret.size() == 0? "0" : ret;
   }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Very simple Algorithm come to mine mind

1. Consider input number as string
2. Start backward looping from number 9 to 0
3. check if 9 exist in given number(in java we can do  it with `indexOf()`), if exists remove. check if number of removed digit are equal to no of input digits to b removed . If not , check 9 existence gaain till it does not exist (`indexOf()` will return -1 under java) to see if same digit is repeated . Now repeat if for 8 till expected no of digit are removed
4. Till now we have removed digit which could contribute to larger number
5. Now loop over from 0 to 9 and check if each digit present in number got in step 3 and rearrange it in ascending order

**For example :-**

Given number is `24635` and no of digit to remove are `2`

1. Start from 9, you find first digit to be removed is 6 then 5
2. Remaining number is 243
3. Start loop from 0 to 9 rearrange it in ascending order like `234`

Answer (score 0):

Knowing that you want to keep digit order certainly makes this solution more difficult.

I do agree with [IVlad](https://stackoverflow.com/users/270287/ivlad) that `char[]`s are not the way to go.

I think this is a fairly good solution:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <limits.h>

#define DIGITS_TO_REMOVE 3 // Assumed to be positive

int recurse(int* foo, int begin, int end, int previous, int max){
    int i;
    int min = begin;

    for (i = begin; i <= end; ++i){
        if (foo[min] > foo[i]){
            min = i;
        }
    }

    return previous * pow(10, max - end + 1) + (max > end ? recurse(foo, min + 1, end + 1, foo[min], max) : foo[min]);
}

int main(void) {
    int foo[(const int)ceil(log10(INT_MAX))];
    int bar = 24635; // Assumed to be larger than pow(10, DIGITS_TO_REMOVE) - 1
    int size = ceil(log10(bar));
    int i;
    int min = size - DIGITS_TO_REMOVE;

    for (i = 1; bar > 0; bar /= 10, ++i){
        foo[size - i] = bar % 10;

        if (i >= DIGITS_TO_REMOVE && foo[size - i] <= foo[min]){
            min = size - i;
        }
    }

    printf("%d", recurse(foo, min + 1, DIGITS_TO_REMOVE + 1, foo[min], size - 1));
    return 0;
}
```

**EDIT:**

[IVlad](https://stackoverflow.com/users/270287/ivlad) also suggested that I make the solution return an array rather than just an `int` so it wouldn't be constrained to the size of the return type. There is obviously some work that would need to go into preparing the input and output array so that may not be the goal of the OP, but it's an interesting problem.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define DIGITS_TO_REMOVE 3 // Assumed to be positive
#define INPUT_SIZE 5 // Assumed to be greater than DIGITS_TO_REMOVE

void recurse(int* input, int* output, int begin, int end){
    int i;
    int min = begin;

    for (i = begin; i < end; ++i){
        if (input[min] > input[i]){
            min = i;
        }
    }
    output[end - DIGITS_TO_REMOVE - 1] = input[min];

    if (end < INPUT_SIZE){
        recurse(input, output, min + 1, end + 1);
    }
}

int main(void) {
    int foo[] = { 2, 4, 6, 3, 5 };
    int bar[INPUT_SIZE - DIGITS_TO_REMOVE];
    int i;

    recurse(foo, bar, 0, DIGITS_TO_REMOVE + 1);

    for (int i = 0; i < INPUT_SIZE - DIGITS_TO_REMOVE; ++i){
        printf("%d", bar[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Apparently you have to write a lot in order to explain why you gave a -1, so I am writing this as formally as possible. I downvoted because this does not solve the OP's problem.

Comment: @IVlad Yeah I did misunderstand the problem on the first pass. The edit cleared it up for me.

Comment: You're using sprintf, logarithms and qsort to solve a simple problem that doesn't need any of that. And your solution only works for numbers that fit in an int. Sorry, but I don't think it's us who are trying to reinvent the wheel here...

Comment: @IVlad Hmmm... You think it would be clearer to do this numerically? I'll have a try at it and see...

Comment: The discussion above seemed to come to the conclusion that the OP probably wants to preserve the original order of digits. I.e. you are allowed to eliminate but not to rearrange. (Although he admittedly didn't make himself perfectly clear.) Example: 22213 -> 13, not 12. Your sorting would destroy the order, as is the manner and purpose of sorting

Comment: @PeterSchneider Ugh, again I appear to have misunderstood the question... working on an edit.

Comment: I think figuring out the question was harder than figuring out the answer. Reminds me of something... ;-).

Comment: I still think that this is needlessly complicated, and you still don't deal with numbers that exceed an int, but it's better, so I removed the -1.

Comment: @IVlad It seems like my solution must be needlessly complex. Cause if you change the types (and `INT_MAX` to `LONG_MAX`) it clearly deals with numbers larger than an `int`.

Comment: @JonathanMee - yes, I know you can change the type, but 19 digits instead of just 10 is hardly a big improvement when other solutions can deal with thousands easily...

Comment: @IVlad I see, you're complaining that my *return* type is an `int` not an array. I suppose that everything would be a bit cleaner if I took in and outputted an `int[]` rather than an `int`...

Comment: Looks much better, +1 :).

Answer (score 0):

I think this will do the trick:

Let's use 532874902352. Try it with anything you want if you feel like it.

With 532874902352, we will remove 4 digits, or any you want.

Move 4+1 digits in. `53287|4902352`

Find the smallest number. `2`

Delete all digits before the chosen one. We have now 28749023532; we deleted 2 digits. 2 more.

Delete 2 digits after the first one. We have 249023532. There we go.

However, if the digit that would be deleted is the second to last one, delete the last one if it is greater than the second to last one.

Examples:

24635, remove 3.

Move in 3+1.

2463|5

Delete all before 2, the smallest.

24635

Delete to fulfill the amount of digits needed, 3.
But delete 5 instead of 3.

23

43331, remove 3.

Move in 3+1.

4333|1

Delete all before 3, the smallest.

31

Delete to fulfill the amount of digits needed, 3.
We have no more digits to delete.

It's up to you to implement this method.

Answer (score 0):

```
private static int getLeastNumberAfterDelete(int num, int dighitsDel) {
 String s = "";
 char[] charArray = String.valueOf(num).toCharArray();
 Arrays.sort(charArray); // Sort charArray
 for (int i = 0; i < (charArray.length - dighitsDel); i++) {
 s += charArray[i];//concatenate 
 }
 return Integer.valueOf(s);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The idea is based on the fact that a character among first (n+1) characters must be there in resultant number. So we pick the smallest of first (n+1) digits and put it in result, and recur for remaining characters. Below is complete algorithm.

> Initialize result as empty string i.e. res = ""
>
> **buildLowestNumber(str, n, res)**
>
> 1) If n == 0, then there is nothing to remove. 
>   Append the whole 'str' to 'res' and return
>
> 2) Let 'len' be length of 'str'. If 'len' is smaller or equal to
>   n, then everything can be removed. Append nothing to 'res' and
>   return
>
> 3) Find the smallest character among first (n+1) characters of
>   'str'. Let the index of smallest character be minIndex. Append
>   'str[minIndex]' to 'res' and recur for substring after minIndex and
>   for n = n-minIndex
>
> buildLowestNumber(str[minIndex+1..len-1], n-minIndex).

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

// A recursive function that removes 'n' characters from 'str'
// to store the smallest possible number in 'res'
void buildLowestNumberRec(string str, int n, string &res)
{
    // If there are 0 characters to remove from str,
    // append everything to result
    if (n == 0)
    {
        res.append(str);
        return;
    }

    int len = str.length();

    // If there are more characters to remove than string
    // length, then append nothing to result
    if (len <= n)
        return;

    // Find the smallest character among first (n+1) characters
    // of str.
    int minIndex = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i<=n ; i++)
        if (str[i] < str[minIndex])
            minIndex = i;

    // Append the smallest character to result
    res.push_back(str[minIndex]);

    // substring starting from minIndex+1 to str.length() - 1.
    string new_str = str.substr(minIndex+1, len-minIndex);

    // Recur for the above substring and n equals to n-minIndex
    buildLowestNumberRec(new_str, n-minIndex, res);
}

// A wrapper over buildLowestNumberRec()
string buildLowestNumber(string str, int n)
{
    string res = "";

    // Note that result is passed by reference
    buildLowestNumberRec(str, n, res);

    return res;
}

// Driver program to test above function
int main()
{
    string str = "121198";
    int n = 2;
    cout << buildLowestNumber(str, n);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
#include <queue>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <algorithm>
#define mod 1000000007
#define ll long long
using namespace std;
bool Compare (pair<int, int> p1, pair<int, int> p2)  {
    if (p1.first < p2.first) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
int main() {
    priority_queue <pair<int, int>, vector <pair <int, int> >, function<bool (pair <int, int>, pair <int, int>) > > pq (Compare);
    int n, k;
    cin>>n>>k;
    int i = 1;
    while (n) {
        pq.push(make_pair(n%10, i));
        n = n/10;
        i++;
    }
    for(int j =1; j<=k;j++){
        pq.pop();
    }
    int number = pq.top().first;
    int index = pq.top().second;
    int digit = 1;
    pq.pop();
    while(!pq.empty()){
        int current_index = pq.top().second;
        digit = digit * 10;
        if(current_index < index) {
            number = number * 10 + pq.top().first;
        } else {
            number = digit * pq.top().first + number;
        }
        pq.pop();
    }
    cout<<number<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I solved the question using priority_queue with pair. please let me know if there is any better solution

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to traverse through the string from the beginning and remove the first digit which is greater than the digit following it.
If no such digit exists, remove the last digit.

```
    class Solution {
    private:
        void removeOneDigit(string& s){
            for(int i=0; i<s.length()-1; i++){
                if(s[i+1]<s[i]){
                    s.erase(i,1);
                    return;
                }
            }
            s.erase(s.length()-1,1);
        }
    public:
        string removeKdigits(string num, int k) {
            for(int i=0; i<k; i++){
                removeOneDigit(num);
            }
            int i=0;
            while(num[i]=='0'){
                num.erase(0,1);
            }
            if(num.length()==0){return "0";}
            return num;
        }
    };
```