# algorithm proof - building least number after deleting k digits from an n-digit number

Tags: algorithm, proof

> Problem: given an n-digit number, which k (k < n) digits should be deleted from it to make the number left is the smallest among all cases (the relative sequence of remaining digits should not be changed). e.g. delete 2 digits from '24635', the smallest left number is '235'.

A solution: Delete the first digit (from left to right) which is larger than or equal to its right neighbor, or the last digit, if we cannot find one as such. Repeat this procedure for `k` times. (see [codecareer](http://codercareer.blogspot.com/2013/11/no-48-least-number-after-deleting-digits.html) for reference. There are other solutions such as [geeksforgeeks](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/build-lowest-number-by-removing-n-digits-from-a-given-number/), [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28223817/1050947), but I thought the one described here is more intuitive, so I prefer this one.)

The problem now is, how to prove the solution above is correct, i.e. how can it guarantee the final number is smallest by making it the smallest after deleting a single digit at each step.

Comment: leading zero in the left number is allowed. e.g. delete one digit from '1028', the left number is '028'.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose `k = 1`.

Let `m = Σi=0,...,n aibi` and `n+1` digit number `anan-1...a1a0` with base `b`, i.e. `0 ≤ ai < b   ∀ 0 ≤ i ≤ n` (e.g. `b = 10`).

#### Proof

`∃ j > 0` with `aj > aj-1` and let `j` be maximal.
 This means `aj` is the last digit of a (not necessary strictly) increasing sequence of consecutive digits. 
 Then the digit `aj` is now removed from the number and the resulting number `m'` has the value

```
m' = Σi=0,...,j-1 aibi   +   Σi=j+1,...,n aibi-1
```

The aim of this reduction is to maximize the difference `m-m'`. So lets take a look:

```
m - m' = Σi=0,...,n aibi - (Σi=0,...,j-1 aibi   +   Σi=j+1,...,n aibi-1)
       = ajbj + Σi=j+1,...,n (aibi - aibi-1)
       = anbn + Σi=j,...,n-1 (ai - ai+1)bi
```

Can there be a better choice of `j` to get a bigger difference?

- Since `an...aj` is an increasing sub sequence,  `ai-ai+1 ≥ 0` holds. So choosing `j' > j` instead of `j`, you get more zeros where you now have a positive number, i.e. the difference gets not bigger, but lower if there exists an `i` with `ai+1 < ai` (strict smaller).
- `j` is supposed to be maximal, i.e. `aj-1-aj < 0`. We know

  ```
  bj-1 > Σi=0,...,j-2(b-1)bi = bi-1-1
  ```

  This means, that if we choose `j' < j', we get a negative addition to the difference, so it also gets not bigger.

If `∄ j > 0` with `aj > aj-1` the above proof works for `j = 0`.

#### What is left to do?

This is only the proof that your algorithm works for `k = 1`.

It is possible to extend the above proof to multiple sub sequences of (not necessary strictly) increasing digits. It's exact the same proof but much less readable, due to the number of indexes you need.

Maybe you can also use induction, since there are no interactions between the digits (blocking following next choices or something).

Comment: The proof about correctness of multiple deletions together is the hard part to me, I'll check if it's the same as a single deletion according to your analysis.

Comment: @zhangwt With induction you are immediately at the end: You get the smallest number with one digit less. If `k > 1`, you go on with `k' = k - 1`. you get a sequence of numbers such that the numbers decreases always by 1 and the number is always the smallest number you can get from the previous by deleting one digit. This proves that your algorithm is correct for `k > 1`.

Comment: I thought there is an implicit assumption in the induction process above, which needs proof. As the induction paradigm, suppose after `j (j<k)` deletions, the number left is currently the smallest, say `A<sub>j</sub>`, which is `n-j` digits. When performing the `j+1` deletion, we get `A<sub>j+1</sub>` based on `A<sub>j</sub>`, and indeed this is the smallest number we can get from `A<sub>j</sub>`.  (see follow comments).

Comment: But competitors to `A<sub>j+1</sub>` include not only what we get from `A<sub>j</sub>` by deleting one more digit, but also those got by deleting one digit from any `n-j` digit number, say `A'<sub>j</sub>`, which is different from `A<sub>j</sub>`, i.e. we get it by deleting different `j` digits than `A<sub>j</sub>`. Thus we also need to prove that `A<sub>j+1</sub>` is smaller than any number, say `A'<sub>j+1</sub>`, got by deleting one digit from `A'<sub>j</sub>`, given that `A<sub>j</sub> < A'<sub>j</sub>`.  (see follow comments)

Comment: For example, `A<sub>j</sub>=3864 < A'<sub>j</sub>=3954`, after deleting one digits, `A<sub>j+1</sub>=364 > A'<sub>j+1</sub>=354`. This is not what we want, and we may need to prove such `A'<sub>j</sub>=3954` would not happen.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple argument that your algorithm works for any k. Suppose there is a digit in the mth place that is less than or equal to it's right (m+1)th digit neighbor, and you delete the mth digit but not the (m+1)th. Then you can delete the (m+1)th digit instead of the mth, and you will get an answer less than or equal to your original answer.

Comment: I thought there might be some different referring about `k` here. Do you let `k` mean the position of digit to delete in the argument. It's intended to be the total number of digits to delete in the problem statement, which is also the case in @AbcAeffchen 's answer I think. Thus you're also giving an argument about deleting a single digit I thought, which is `k=1` in the context of @AbcAeffchen 's answer.

Comment: @zhangwt I abused notation for k by letting it be the index of a deleted digit. Now I changed the index to m. The argument should work for any number k of deleted digits.

Comment: I'm still not sure about the proof of multiple deletions, please see the comments to @AbcAeffchen.

Answer (score 0):

**notice**: this proof is for building the maximum number after removing k digits, but the thinking is similar

> key lemma: maximum (m + 1)-digit number contains maximum m-digit
>   number for all m = 0, 1, ..., n - 1

proof:

- greedy solution to delete `one` digit from some number to get the maximum
  result: just delete `the first digit which next digit is greater than it`, or `the last digit if digits are in non-ascending order`. This is very easy to prove.

we use contradiction to proof the lemma.

1. suppose the first time the lemma is broken when m = k, so `S(k) ⊄ S(k + 1)`. Notice that the `S(k) ⊂ S(n)` as the initial number contains all sub optimal ones, so there must exist a `x` that `S(k) ⊂ S(x)` and `S(k) ⊄ S(x - 1)`, `k + 2 <= x <= n`
2. we use the greedy solution above to delete only one digit `S[X][y]` from S(x) to get S(x - 1), so `S[X][y] ∈ S(x)` and `S[X][y] ∉ S(x - 1)` and `S(k)` must contain it. `We now use contradiction to prove that S(k) does not need to contain this digit .`

> According to our greedy solution, all digits from beginning to S[X][y] are
>   in non-ascending order.

3. if `S[X][y] is at the tail`, then `S(k) can be the first k digits of S(x)` ---> contradiction!
4. otherwise, we firstly know that all digits in `S[X][1, 2,..., y] are in S[k]`. If there is a `S[X][z] is not in`S(k)`, 1 <= z <= y - 1`, then we can shift digits of `S(k)` that in range `S[X][z + 1, y]` to `left one unit` to get a greater or equal S(k). Therefore, there are at least `2` digit `after S[X][y]` that are `not in S(k)` as `x >= k + 2`. Then, we can follow the `prefix of S(k)` to S[X][y], but we do `not` use `S[X][y]`, we use from `S[X][y + 1]`. `As S[X][y + 1] > S[X][y], we can build a greater S(k)` -------> contradiction!

so, we prove lemma. If we have got `S(m + 1)`, and we know `S(m + 1) contains S(m)`, then `S(m)` must be the `maximum number after removing one digit` from `S(m + 1)`