# How to get the maximum number after erasing n digits from the number

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures

For example for the number `9511145` if I want to delete 3 digits from this number the maximum number will be `9545`. Deleted digits don't have to be contiguous. However, the relative position of the remaining digits should be left unchanged. The number can be 10<sup>6</sup> digits long. To solve this problem in an iterative approach it could take O(N<sup>2</sup>) time. If anyone could suggest any better way to solve this problem then it would be a great help.

Comment: How is the number represented?  I'm struggling to see how you'd end up with an O(N^2) approach.

Comment: Should the sequence of non-erased digits be kept same in answer?

Comment: Seems similar to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28223580/how-to-get-the-least-number-after-deleting-k-digits-from-the-input-number, which try to find the minimum value.

Comment: I saw it but couldn't catch the the approach from there.Can you please make a answer for this

Comment: If the largest number has magnitude 10^6 it's 6 digits long, and the asymptotic behavior of your algorithm just doesn't matter.

Comment: I made many mistakes to ask this question.It's 10^6 digits long.

Comment: Keep the representation as a string.  You can compare digit characters similarly to numbers.

Comment: Yeah.Got it.. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to this question has been beautifully answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28223817/1040597).
Only difference is you have to keep the stack sorted decreasingly.

```
# process digits from left to right
for each digit from left to right
  if digit <= top of the stack
    push(digit)
    continue
  while (digit > top of the stack) and (we have enough digits to reach n-k digits)
    pop()
  push(digit)
pop extra digits

9511145
push(9) => 9
push(5) because 5 <= 9 => 95
push(1) because 1 <= 5 => 951
push(1) because 1 <= 1 => 9511
push(1) because 1 <= 1 => 95111
pop() because 4 > 1 and we can still end up with 4 digits => 9511
pop() because 4 > 1 and we can still end up with 4 digits => 951
pop() because 4 > 1 and we can still end up with 4 digits => 95
push(4) because 4 <= 5 => 954
push(5) because we need to have 4 digits at least => 9545
```

## NOTE: upvote original [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28223817/1040597).

Comment: Second last reason (4<5) seems to be wrong. Since even if you have 6 in place of 4, you need to append last two digits anyways to make the number 4 digits long.

Comment: Thanks brother.@sudonakeinstall2

Comment: Awesome explanation.. But my reputation doesn't allow me to up vote your solution.. It's my bad luck.. Lots of thanks

Comment: @JahirulIslamMonir Don't worry man I just explained another dude's solution. I don't deserve rep for this ;)

Comment: You explained even much better from that solution... Thanks man

Comment: look at the example. when we want to push 4 we repeatedly pop 1s from the stack. because they are less than 4

Comment: Yeah Got it.Thanks